# elseif statement with foreach loop error in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement

I am trying to do a if else statement with a foreach loop but for some reason I am getting this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'elseif' (T_ELSEIF).

I know that this is a simple error but I can't seem to identify what is wrong here, did I do my code wrongly? Or is it something that need to be closed? (for the closing part, I have checked and I don't really see any problem with it) Can someone help me? Thanks a lot

`profile.blade.php`

```
@foreach($data as $value) 
  <tr> 
 @if($value->training_Status == 'No')
 <th><a href="{{route('user.show',['id'=>$value->pi_id])}}"><span style="color: blue;">{{$value->Name}}</span></a></th>
 @foreach($data1 as $value1)
  @elseif(($value1->blacklist == 'Yes') && ($value1->name == $value->Name))
 <th><a href="{{route('user.show',['id'=>$value->pi_id])}}"><span style="color: red;">{{$value->Name}}</span></a></th>
  @endforeach
 @else 
<th><a href="{{route('user.show',['id'=>$value->pi_id])}}">{{$value->Name}}</a></th>
 @endif 
 </tr> 
 @endforeach
```

Comment: `@foreach` and `@endforeach` are in two completely different code-blocks.

Comment: You mean the foreach I have put the place wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change to

```
@foreach($data as $value) 
  <tr> 
 @if($value->training_Status == 'No')
 <th><a href="{{route('user.show',['id'=>$value->pi_id])}}"><span style="color: blue;">{{$value->Name}}</span></a></th>
 @foreach($data1 as $value1)
  @if(($value1->blacklist == 'Yes') && ($value1->name == $value->Name))
 <th><a href="{{route('user.show',['id'=>$value->pi_id])}}"><span style="color: red;">{{$value->Name}}</span></a></th>
     @endif 
  @endforeach
 @else 
<th><a href="{{route('user.show',['id'=>$value->pi_id])}}">{{$value->Name}}</a></th>
 @endif 
 </tr> 
 @endforeach
```

Comment: Ohh it was the problem with endif but in the past when I didn't put in the second foreach, the @endif just need to put it 1 time, why do I need to put it twice now?

Comment: because the second `foreach` contains an `if` ...  before there was 1 `if` so 1 `endif` ... now there are 2 `if`s, so 2 `endif`s ... if there was 3 `if`s there would be 3 `endif`s ... if there was 4 ...

Comment: But can't we just use elseif instead of the seond if? Why do I need to use another if instead?

Comment: because its not part of the previous conditionals, its a new logical condition at that point in the code in this current block .. there is a structure for the language and logic, its fundamental

Answer (score 1):

```
@foreach($data as $value) 
 <tr> 
 @if($value->training_Status == 'No')
   <th><a href="{{route('user.show',['id'=>$value->pi_id])}}"><span style="color: blue;">{{$value->Name}}</span></a></th>
   @foreach($data1 as $value1)
     @if(($value1->blacklist == 'Yes') && ($value1->name == $value->Name))
     <th><a href="{{route('user.show',['id'=>$value->pi_id])}}"><span style="color: red;">{{$value->Name}}</span></a></th>
     @endif 
   @endforeach
 @else 
   <th><a href="{{route('user.show',['id'=>$value->pi_id])}}">{{$value->Name}}</a></th>
 @endif 
 </tr> 
 @endforeach
```

Should do the job for you

Answer (score 1):

@Dkna Just change your code to like this:

```
@foreach($data as $value) 
    <tr> 
    @if($value->training_Status == 'No')
       <th><a href="{{route('user.show',['id'=>$value->pi_id])}}"><span style="color: blue;">{{$value->Name}}</span></a></th>
       @foreach($data1 as $value1)
           @if(($value1->blacklist == 'Yes') && ($value1->name == $value->Name))
              <th><a href="{{route('user.show',['id'=>$value->pi_id])}}"><span style="color: red;">{{$value->Name}}</span></a></th>
           @endif 
       @endforeach
    @else 
        <th><a href="{{route('user.show',['id'=>$value->pi_id])}}">{{$value->Name}}</a></th>
    @endif 
    </tr> 
@endforeach
```

Hope this helps you and fixed your issue!